# How to merge overlapping shadows?

Tags: light, lighting, eevee-render-engine, shadows

my shadows are overlapping and have light outlines around them on top of other shadows creating a very ugly effect, I have a screenshot below to demonstrate the issue.

The red outlines show the object that is casting one of the shadows, it is not just this single object though, the roof tiles and wood under the roof is doing the same thing.

I can send more images or give more information if needed any help would be appreciated :)

[image: image of overlapping shadows]

Also the light source is a sun lamp.